# Facebook like button does "like" and "unlike" actions in quick succession. Script sometimes gives "FB.init has already been called "

Tags: facebook, button, joomla, facebook-like, addthis

As in title users Just can't get the like button to work properly on my site.
When they click, at first the button seems to work but it soon gets "unclicked/not liked".

This is a sample link: http://www.lostradone.it/archivio-news/47-politica/2843-schittulli-duro-con-la-politica-nazionale-abbiamo-solo-yes-men

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was related to a Joomla Component (System Language) which were passing  the wrong url to the Facebook Like Button, adding to it the language code suffix.

When facebook tried to fetch the url a 404 error were given so the button weren't working. Once disabled the Language plugin the button started working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

That happens when Facebook put’s your site on some kind of index, most likely for having to much linke/dislike action over a short period of time.

You can wait for it to go away by itself – but I find it sometimes helps to send a message through some problem notification form in the Facebook help section (don’t ask me where, have a look around). Normally you don’t get an answer, but I’ve done it two times already and both times the error disappeared shortly afterwards …

Comment: I've post my personal answer but thanks anyway for your interest! Your solution may be valid in other circumstances.